# Need an explanation for this javascript function code which executes multiple functions on a single input

Tags: javascript

Question:Your task is to write a higher order function for chaining together a list of unary functions. In other words, it should return a function that does a left fold on the given functions.
example:
chained([a,b,c,d])(input)

Should yield the same result as

d(c(b(a(input))))

```
function chained(functions) {              //1
  return function(input){                   //2
    return functions.reduce(function(input, fn){ return fn(input) }, input);        //3
  }
}
```

```
function f1(x){ return x*2 }
function f2(x){ return x+2 }
function f3(x){ return Math.pow(x,2) }
```

and output this in console.log

```
console.log(chained([f1,f2,f3])(0));
```

output: 4

My Question is how the function is distinguishing between function array i.e [f1,f2,f3]) and input (0) when both are define like chained([f1,f2,f3])(0)
if you console.log(input) in line //2 we will get 0 , how its getting the input and the reduce part as well,that's my question.

Comment: The arity is never explicitly checked, however `fn(input)` only passes a single argument to each function, so if the arity is more than 1 (and the rest of the parameters are required), then it's going to be a problem. Unary functions are guaranteed to work. Technically, so would a function that has no parameters.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but `chained([f1,f2,f3])` returns a function waiting for a single `input` argument. adding `(0)` to the end calls that returned function immediately with `0` as `input`. Maybe this is clearer: `const f4 = chained([f1,f2,f3]); f4(0); // -> 4`. In this example, `f4` is the function returned by calling `chained`, and it is awaiting a single `input` argument.

Comment: Thanks guys , i got it.